# Files structure in MVVM (Android)

Tags: android, mvvm, structure, mvp

using MVVM or MVP should i name packages like model, viewmodel, view and put proper classes and interfaces there or is it just a logical structure that should not be visible in classes structure?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to go by the book, the current "correct" way to implement MVVM in Android is the **Android Architecture Components** set of libraries.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html), and try [this code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#0). These will also show you how to name and place your classes.

But in general, you should go with what matches your app best. For smaller apps I would recommend going with M V P folders, while for bigger, more long-term ones tend to work better with folder-per-feature structure.

Answer (score 15):

Google in it's sample Android Architecture project uses Model(Data) V(views) VM(view-models) file structure
[Google sample sunflower app to show architecture components](https://github.com/android/sunflower)
Probably that's the best approach
[image]

Answer (score 11):

Additionnaly you may find this resource interesting https://overflow.buffer.com/2016/09/26/android-rethinking-package-structure/
An implementation is visible here https://github.com/SamYStudiO/beaver

Comment: That's the first android project structure that actually makes sense to me... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I also would like to indicate watching this [TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4).
This guy goes well on teaching about the **Architecture MVVM** and also uses the **ROOM** Persistence Library.
It is worth giving a look at it.